# Regex to delete between pairs of strings, but not delete everything when multiple pairs

Tags: python, regex

Is there a regex that can take this string:

```
"This is [D>aa <D] a [A>bb <A] test [D>ccc  cc <D]."
```

and return this:

```
"This is a [A>bb <A] test."
```

So essentially deletes everything that starts with `[D>` and ends with `<D]`. This can't be straight forward because these pairs pop up multiple times, so using the regex `[[D>].*[<D]]` returns:

```
"This is ."
```

Comment: Can these pairs be nested?

Comment: I think you need to learn about greedy and non-greedy operators. Try replacing `.*` with `.*?`.

Comment: they cannot be nested

Comment: Then you can simply use `\[D>.*?<D\]`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `.*` quantifier is greedy. This means it matches 0 or more characters, as many times as possible, so your first match stretches all the way to the end of your second match. By changing it to `.*?` it makes it lazy, where it will match 0 or more characters as few times as possible. Here is the pattern:

`\[D>.*?<D\]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RsRdUZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick; note the lazy quantifier `.*?` which will avoid greedily consuming the trailing `<D]`. I added an optional space before the brackets to clean up output:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is [D>aa <D] a [A>bb <A] test [D>ccc  cc <D]."
>>> re.sub(r"( ?\[D>.*?<D\])", "", s)
'This is a [A>bb <A] test.'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pairs always start with `[D>`  and are always matched by `<D]` you might match a whitespace, then match `[D>` followed by matching not a closing square bracket using a negated character class `[^]]+` and at the end match a closing square bracket.

Then use [sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=sub#re.sub) and replace with an empty string

`[ ]\[D>[^]]+\]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/amoPSO/1)

```
import re
s = "This is [D>aa <D] a [A>bb <A] test [D>ccc  cc <D]."
print(re.sub(r"[ ]\[D[^]]+\]", "", s)) # This is a [A>bb <A] test.
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SABU51879)